# Bostich Finish nailer hanging up

Tags: repair

My Finish nailer will shoot just fine. Afterwards, it hangs up or sticks. Doesn't reset immediately. There is always a 5- 10 second delay, unless I disconnect air hose. I don't like doing that because it will sometimes fire another nail after re-connecting air. Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you, Dane.

Comment: I bet that "will sometimes fire another nail after re-connecting air" is a significant clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Is the air pressure set within the allowable range for the tool?

Answer (score 1):

I've only used a few pneumatics in my time & one that was doing the same thing, turned out to need a re-build. [**Here's one place to find parts or maybe a re-build kit.**](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/bostitch-n59fn-pneumatic-finish-nailer-parts-c-29443_29458_203274.html) The owner of the tool tried lubrication, but it didn't do anything. I was told at the time, by another carpenter, that any abnormal behavior is the beginning signs of gasket wear.

So, I got a re-build kit from a non-local heck of a haul Bostitch dealer/distributor. Due to, my local Vac & Sew place only doing staplers & the Electronics & Power Equipment Repair places not doing pneumatics at all. A new spring here & a new seal, there, there, there & there. And, the problem was gone forever, as far as I knew, & the tool owner was pleased as punch.

Comment: So what is your answer?    Also if you don't have experience with pneumatics or repairing them I am wondering why you are answering?  Just curious.

Comment: I believe @iggy said the one time this was a problem a rebuild fixed it.

Comment: @EdBeal - Rebuild isn't an answer, you could say that when any piece of machinery quits working right.  Like telling someone to rebuild their car if there is smoke coming from radiator.

Comment: "Re-build" is just referencing the same type of re-build you do to a kitchen faucet. Simply replacing a very few wearable parts. Depending upon his Model, the website I provided does have some Re-build or Seal Renewal Kits. $20 is & was worth a shot & it worked marvelously.

Comment: I did not notice the link for the repair rebuild kit before +

Comment: The link is just an example since I don't know his model #, depending upon the model he'd find the repair kit in the parts list, usually at the bottom. Half of the models on that site have kits, just some springs & a bunch of O-rings, they're pretty obvious.